# Get the number of documents liked per document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sql-like

I'm working on a project by using MongoDB as a database and I'm encountering a problem: I can't find the right query to make a simple count of the likes of a document. The collection that I use is this :

```
{ "username" : "example1",
  "like" : [ { "document_id" : "doc1" },
                "document_id" : "doc2 },
                 ...]
}
```

So what I need is to compute is the number of likes of each document so at the end I will have

```
{ "document_id" : "docA" , nbLikes : 30 }, {"document_id" : "docB", nbLikes : 1}
```

Can anyone help me  on this because I failed.

Comment: What I was thinking as a solution is to retrieve all the documents so that we will have [{"document_id" : "doc1"}, {"document_id" : "doc2"}, {"document_id" : "doc1"}, {"document_id" : "doc3"}...] And then make group and count. But is it possible to do the first step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by unwinding the `like` array of each doc and then grouping by `document_id` to get a count for each value:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    // Duplicate each doc, once per 'like' array element
    {$unwind: '$like'},
    // Group them by document_id and assemble a count
    {$group: {_id: '$like.document_id', nbLikes: {$sum: 1}}},
    // Reshape the docs to match the desired output
    {$project: {_id: 0, document_id: '$_id', nbLikes: 1}}
])
```

Comment: It works like a charm thank you. I have only add a small optimisation:
db.favorites.aggregate([
    {$project : {username:1,likes:1}}, 
    {$unwind: '$likes'},
    {$group: {_id: '$likes.document_id', nbLikes: {$sum: 1}}},
    {$project: {_id: 0, document_id: '$_id', nbLikes: 1}}
])
because my collection is more complex than that

Answer (score 0):

Add "likeCount" field and increase count for per $push operation and read "likeCount" field

```
db.test.update(
   { _id: "..." },
   { 
       $inc: { likeCount: 1 }, 
       $push: { like: { "document_id" : "doc1" } }
    }
)
```